# Is it legal to use the TM symbol?

Tags: trademark

I am making a game, and I have a worries is it legal to use the Trademark Symbol in the logo of the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ™  symbol, is similar to the (c) symbol. There are both used to assert trademarks and copyright respectively. ™ is for unregistered trademarks, while (r) is.

As Dale points out, it's illegal to assert or use a trademark that isn't yours, as it is false and misleading. Using a trademark that is not yours is known as [brand piracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_piracy).

Comment: So, it's legal to use TM to a logo, that doesn't have any declaration or similar?

Comment: The question was about using the TM logo on what looks like is not a trademark, not using a the TM logo on a trademark that belongs to someone else.

Comment: @GabrielDiego Umm... What? He's asking if he can use the tm symbol on his own unregistered trademark.

Answer (score -2):

If you have registered the logo as a trade mark, yes. If not, it is a false and misleading representation (aka a lie) and is illegal in most jurisdictions.

Comment: Lying is not illegal.

Comment: This is incorrect (at least in the United States). A mark's owner should use TM in the case that a mark is *not* registered. Using TM on a registered mark is incorrect; in that case, the owner should use (R).